# Get span's child element with jquery

Tags: jquery

I have nodes like:

```
<td id="finalstep_x">
  <div class="mydiv">
    <span class="ui-icon-stop"></span>
    Caption_X
  </div>
</td>
```

and once I got the td element as current with calling:

```
.find('td[id^=finalstep_]')
```

what would be best way to catch the span element to toggle the ui-icon-stop class with ui-icon-check class and viceversa?

Thanks everyone! 
Cheers,
Luigi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use space to indicate descendant along with **[.toggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)** to toggle the classes:

```
.find('td[id^="finalstep_"] span').toggleClass('ui-icon-check ui-icon-stop')
```

Also note that your id contain special character `_` so you need to wrap it inside double quotes `" "`.

Comment: This will work the first time, he needs to toggle between ui-icon-check and ui-icon-stop. This will not work for ui-icon-check span.

Comment: Thanks Felix, it worked! Obviously I had to manage two states so it would toggle viceversa :-) And thanks to all everyone for your answers :)

Comment: Still prefers the C-Link answer, no need of manage two states.

Answer (score 3):

You should use quotes around attribute value while using `name-attribute` selector:

```
find('td[id^="finalstep_"]');
//           ^  HERE    ^
```

and for toggling class:

```
$('td[id^="finalstep_"]').find('span').toggleClass("ui-icon-check  ui-icon-stop");
```

Comment: @C-link: id has special characters in it.

Comment: Oh! I had not cared that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use like this:

```
.find('td[id^="finalstep_"]').find('[class^="ui-icon"]').toggleClass("ui-icon-check  ui-icon-stop");
```